# Can I create Google App user, then sign them in, all using API?

Tags: google-api, single-sign-on

I want my authenticated website users (non Google users) to access private Youtube videos. Can I do the following:

1. Create a Google Apps user account on my domain name;
2. Share a specific private youtube video with that new Google user;
3. When user wants to access a private video on my google account, then
   my application signs them into the new account, then redirects them
   to the private video.
4. All of this happens without the user ever having to type in the new
   Google user account username or password.

Thanks.

Comment: Probably not and if there was a way of doing it its most likely too broad a question for stack.     YouTube API doesn't allow for service accounts so this would be a major Oauth Hack if you did get it working.

Comment: How do you authenticate your non-Google website users? Do you have a SAML 2.0 Identity Provider?